# Need help to design a voltage regulator circuit for two 3v dc motors

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, dc, dc-motor, dc-dc-converter

**I intend to use two DC 3V motors to make a mini water pump as [described in this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIkP_GUlPqE)**

Here are the specs of my **solar panel** which i intend to use as power supply for the circuit:

- Voltage at max power point=8.2V.
- Current at max power point=0.62A.
- Nominal voltage=6V.
- Power at max power point=5W.

I have two DC motors each of 3V rating.[image: This is the dc motor which i have]

I don't know the power consumption of this motor under loaded conditions.I  got a datasheet of a motor looking exactly like mine from a website.-->[This is the link to it](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1662763.pdf?_ga=2.199037416.679386486.1529140502-1357347678.1529140502).According to it ,**the  motor consumes 0.76A at 1.5V at max efficiency and 1.1A at 3V at max efficiency.**

1)Assuming that the panel gives about 3.5 to 4 Watt during the time of usage, how do i convert its output to 1.2A at 3V or to 2.4A at 1.5V with minimum loss?

2)Are LM317 or 78xx series ICs good enough to accomplish the  task?

Comment: I would suggest to buy one buck regulator. Not to lose already limited power as heat in the regulators.

Comment: that pump seems likely to leak

Comment: can you get the same motor in 12V rating?

Comment: @Jasen I have a generic 12V motor but i do not have its specifications.When i connected it directly to my panel it ran fine although i am unable to measure the rpm and other parameters. I am doing this for a high school science project and i don't want to buy a bigger panel.

Comment: "runs fine" is probably good enough, I wouldn't guess that that pump design will run for more than a few hours.

Comment: @Jasen I do not need to use it for long and continuous operation. I would run it for few minutes after i build it. Then take it to my school and run it for few minutes to prove to my teacher that i have a working model. So do you think i should use a 12V motor?

Comment: @Umar Can you suggest me a cheap buck regulator for the above parameters?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/DROK-Regulator-Converter-Electronic-Stabilizer/dp/B07CR4N51V/ref=mp_s_a_1_11/143-9885031-4661067?ie=UTF8&qid=1529253433&sr=8-11&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=buck%2Bvoltage%2Bregulator&dpPl=1&dpID=41DsSAF9syL&ref=plSrch&th=1&psc=1 please see buck regulator on similar lines.. Most of them come with variable output voltages

Comment: @Umar  I have one more doubt. Is there any problem if the motor tries to take more than the max current from the solar panel? Will the panel get damaged or anything?

Comment: Since you are using regulator, depending on regulator the behavior may change. It will not destroy the solar panel (my gut feeling).  over load protection circuits can be used but it may be a over kill.. Experiment with the Regulator you have, unless regulator already has built in protection

Comment: Solar panel will not be harmed for sure.